# Terminating data link when specific word such as when 'Exit' is sent to server in C 'Client-Server' Program

Tags: c, tcp

The first given task I must complete is by editing the following code to satisfy the criteria of terminating the data link when a client sends a specific word or number to the server. This C program uses simplex-talk method to communicate from client to server. Essentially the socket interface sends messages over a TCP connection.
Any solutions?

**Current Given Server Code:**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main()
{
struct sockaddr_in sin;
char buf[MAX_LINE];
int buf_len, addr_len;
int s, new_s;
/* build address data structure */
bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
/* setup passive open */
if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: socket");
exit(1);
}
if ((bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: bind");
exit(1);
}

listen(s, MAX_PENDING);
/* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
while(1) {
if ((new_s = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &addr_len)) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: accept");
exit(1);
}
while (buf_len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0))
fputs(buf, stdout);
close(new_s);
}
}
```

**Current Given Client Code:**

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
FILE *fp;
struct hostent *hp;
struct sockaddr_in sin;
char *host;
char buf[MAX_LINE];
int s;
int len;
if (argc==2) {
host = argv[1];
}
else {
fprintf(stderr, "usage: simplex-talk host\n");
exit(1);
}
/* translate host name into peer's IP address */
hp = gethostbyname(host);
if (!hp) {
fprintf(stderr, "simplex-talk: unknown host: %s\n", host);
exit(1);
}
/* build address data structure */
bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
/* active open */
if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: socket");
exit(1);
}
if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0)
{
perror("simplex-talk: connect");
close(s);
exit(1);
}

/* main loop: get and send lines of text */
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
len = strlen(buf) + 1;
send(s, buf, len, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code properly

Comment: Assured way is to use [TLV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value) buffers for communications.